# Concat (2 fields) LIKE submitted value using Propel/Mysql/PHP

Tags: php, mysql, propel

Propel/PHP/Mysql question for you.  I have a search box that will search names in a table.  I need to concat 2 fields, first_name and last_name, and than do a LIKE % submitted string %.  All in propel.

This is what I currently have:

```
        $custQuery = CustomerQuery::create()
            ->withColumn("CONCAT(first_name, ' ', last_name)", "full_name")
            ->where("full_name LIKE %?%", $nameInput);
```

This gives the error:

```
Cannot determine the column to bind to the parameter in clause "full_name = ?".
```

Obviously I can't use the virtual column in the where statement.  When I try to do the concat inside the where statement, I get the same error.

```
        $custQuery = CustomersQuery::create()
            ->where("CONCAT(first_name, ' ', last_name) LIKE %?%", $searchStr);
```

I'd prefer to avoid doing this without parameters:

```
        $custQuery = CustomersQuery::create()
            ->where("CONCAT(first_name, ' ', last_name) LIKE %$searchStr%");
```

It works, but I am looking for a more propel orientated method of doing this.  Is there a way to do this without a where statement at all?

Thanks a ton!

Comment: I don't know propel but as mysql is concern 
SELECT CONCAT(first_name, " ",last_name ) AS full_name FROM tablename;  
It will return you the concatenated name.

Comment: The last query I posted is that without the "AS."  I am using that, and it works.  I'd rather use actual propel to do this if possible.

Comment: Yes, you are not using 'As' because Propel does it for you. As you have sent full_name as parameter to withColumn()

Comment: I'm confused.  In the first query I posted above, I am using withcolumn and setting an alias.  I get the same error using that query.  If I use a full where: ->where("CONCAT("first_name, " ", "last_name") as full_name LIKE %?%, $inputStr) I get the above error.  The only way to make it work is to remove the parameter completely as you see I did in the final query above.  This works, but isn't the way I'd like to do it.  There isn't another way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to use pseudo column names. So, if your normal filter method for the customers.first_name column is `->filterByFirstName()`, then when you use a `->where()` or a `->condition()` method, you also have to use the "FirstName" pseudo column name instead of 'first_name'.

So, your problem query:

```
 $custQuery = CustomersQuery::create()
            ->where("CONCAT(first_name, ' ', last_name) LIKE %?%", $searchStr);
```

would become:

```
$custQuery = CustomersQuery::create()
            ->where("CONCAT(Customers.FirstName, ' ', Customers.LastName) LIKE ?", '%'.$searchStr.'%');
```

I added the table name in there for you too for good measure, and you need to make the percent signs part of the paramater instead of part of the query statement.